# How to deploy Selenium Grid in Azure DevTestLabs

Tags: c#, azure, selenium-rc, selenium-grid, azure-devtest-labs

I'm trying to execute remote selenium tests via Azure.

To do this, I used https://github.com/Azure/azure-devtestlab/tree/master/samples/DevTestLabs/QuickStartTemplates/201-dtl-create-lab-with-seleniumgrid

I create a custom template with the selenium server standalone jar file and installed the Chocolatey Packages, which contains the node and hub artifacts.

I started the virtual machines (the hub and the node). And downloaded the java standalone jar file manually in each vm, and at the command prompt I started each one with the proper commands:

**Hub:**

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -role hub
```

And the hub gave me an IP for the node to connect. *(For this example I'll use: 10.0.0.2)*

**Node**

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\tryGrid\chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -role node -hub http://10.0.0.2:4444/grid/register/
```

But the node couldn't connect to the hub.

So I search in azure forums to solve this problem. I found that I had to add the artifacts. So, in Azure, I went to the DevTest Lab resource I've created, look for every vm and inspect the artifacts. In this case: Manage Artifacts section. Here I found that Selenium-grid hub and Selenium-grid node had an error showed in the Implementation Message. [image]

**Hub:**

> The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state
>   'Failed'. VM has reported a failure when processing extension
>   'customScriptArtifact-183362431'. Error message: "Finished executing
>   command".

**Extension Message:**

> Executing script GridDeployer.ps1
>
> Parameters
>   ---------- Role: hub ConfigFile: testhub SeleniumGridJarFile: https://seleniumserverstandalonejardow
>
> SeleniumGridJarFileName: s4o9Vx Successfully downloaded the
>   SeleniumGrid jar file from https://seleniumserverstandalonejardownload. Invoke-WebRequest :
>   The remote name could not be resolved: 'testhub' At
>   C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.9\Downloads\2\
>   PublicRepo\master\b8dcb684950157e2f6c44e9774ad70f0b27443d3\Artifacts\windows-se
>   leniumgrid-hub\scripts\GridDeployer.ps1:58 char:5
>   +     Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $configFile -OutFile "$PWD\$configFileName"
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt     pWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest],
>   WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe
>   ll.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

So I don't now what I should do. Help!

*PS. I've work with these node and hub configuration in local machines and It works awesome, but the problem is when I want to execute it with azure VMs*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I were able to find the answer to this question. The problem wasn't in the portal azure side but in my virtual machine.

I read a lot of forums and issues on github and another questions here. And finally I found one about a firewall issue.

What did I just do? On my virtual machine I:

1. Went to *Windows Firewall with Advanced Security*
2. Clicked on *Windows Firewall Properties*
3. On *Private and Public Profile* I changed the state of the firewall to **Off.**
4. Click on *Apply* and *OK*

Then, for the **Hub** configuration you can write a json file and save it in the same path as the selenium server. The file should contains something like this:

```
{
  "host": "85.168.37.178",
  "port": 4444,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets" : [],
  "prioritizer": null,
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "nodePolling": 5000,

  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "timeout": 300000,
  "maxSession": 5
}
```

I saved the file as hub.json. And on the console you write

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.6.0.jar -role hub -hubConfig hub.json
```

For the **Node** you can also write a configuration file like this:

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "firefox",
          "maxInstances": 5
        },
        {
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "internet explorer",
          "maxInstances": 1
        }
      ],
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 5,
    "port": 5555,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hub": "http://85.168.37.178:4444/",
    "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
    "nodePolling": 5000,
    "role": "node",
    "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
    "downPollingLimit": 2,
    "debug": false,
    "servlets" : [],
    "withoutServlets": [],
    "custom": {}
}
```

And finally, in your **program** you can write the IP or the DNS, I took the DNS because is public.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://myvirtualmachinename.server.cloudapp.azure.com:4444/wd/hub"), options.ToCapabilities());
```

I hope this works for you too!